# Why I got aborted message when npm install on my online server

Tags: npm, npm-install

I create a node application and it is running on the local server. I need to run it on my online server. I have to install `npm`. When I run the command `npm install` I got this message.

[image: Screen Shot of message]

How can I fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
sudo npm install -d
```

npm should not need sudo except for global installs. Let's start with "how did you install node"? If you're on OSX, use brew to install the latest version, if you're on Windows, grab the installer from nodejs.org, if you're in linux, you should already know what to do